# Flutter: Equatable props getter with optional parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, equatable

I have an object that extends Equatable and contains optional parameters. If I try to add that parameter into the props getter, I get an error `The element type 'String?' can't be assigned to the list type 'Object'`. However, not adding it would imply equality within objects that have a different value or no value in that parameter.

```
class Company extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final String? logo;
....

@override
List<Object> get props {
  return [
    name,
    logo, //error here
....
```

What would the appropriate solution be?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The base [`Equatable.props` getter](https://pub.dev/documentation/equatable/latest/equatable/Equatable/props.html) is declared to return a `List<Object?>`, not `List<Object>`.  Fixing your override to match would allow you to store `null`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I was generating the override with the VSCode quick fix which outputs it without the ?

Comment: What if the String logo needs to be nullable? I have a similar issue and when I make the class property nullable with a ?, the equatable prop throws the error. How do you solve this?

Comment: @user3735816 As I said, `Equatable.props` should have a return type of `List<Object?>`, and that already allows you to have nullable properties.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry. Dumb mistake on my part. Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use dynamic instead of Object